# how to retrieve values that are in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to take all the values from categories.name after that I want to just console the vegetable, so if in the data product there is a vagetable name in categories.name, I want to take that one index

this is a javascript program

```
const product_data = [
  {
    name: "avocado",
    categories: [
      {
        name: "vegetable"
      },
      {
        name: "fruit"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "masako",
    categories: [
      {
        name: "seasoning"
      },
      {
        name: "vegetable"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "apple",
    categories: [
      {
        name: "fruit"
      },
      {
        name: "desert"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

there is no error at all except that I am confused how it works

Comment: "there is no error at all": in what code? You've not provided any code!

Comment: what should the output be ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more clear on your question please.

I suggest you to use underscore.js to pluck the values and find the count of index

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your are asking about?

```
// loop over the product_data array size
for(var i=0;i<product_data.length;i++){
  let item = product_data[i];

  // then loop over the individual obect entry's category size
  for(var x=0;x<item.categories.length;x++){

    // if its a vegetable
    if('vegetable'===item.categories[x].name){
      console.log(
        'Category: ' + item.categories[x].name
        + ' - Item: ' + item.name);
    }
  }
}
```